# More about taking the liberty of doing something

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-usage

Please have a look on my three sets below:

1)

> a) I take the liberty to disagree. 
>   b) I venture to disagree.

2)

> a) I take the liberty to say that... 
>   b) I venture to say that...

3)

> a) I would like to take the liberty to say that... 
>   b) I would like to venture that...

I think in all of my sets below 'b' versions sound incorrect. Am I right?

Comment: Why you think they seem incorrect? Why you think all A's are correct? Did you check the difference between 'liberty' and 'venture'? What confused you?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. I'll provide my answer in five parts.

#### “Taking the liberty”

First of all, there's the notion of *taking the liberty* to do something. It doesn't sound wrong, but it doesn't sound contemporary, either. I looked for usages in Google books, and found plenty of hits, but most were in more antiquated contexts. So I went to [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=took%20the%20liberty%20to,take%20the%20liberty%20to,%28have%20the%20right%20to%20*%200.5%29&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=8), and found this very interesting result:

[image]

I asked myself, "If *'I took the liberty to disagree'* sounds old fashioned, what would I say today?" The first thing I thought of was:

> I have the right to disagree.

which yields another interesting Ngram:

[image]

It looks to me like, as talk of "taking liberties" waned, talk about "having rights" was on the rise – at least from an English perspective.

---

#### “Venturing to disagree”

Then there's your question about *venture*. The phrase *venture to disagree* suits me just fine, particularly when you want to emphasize that a little disagreement might be surprising. (I think *dare to disagree* might be more appropriate in more dangerous circumstances; in other words, I might *venture to disagree* with a coworker, but *dare to disagree* with a dictator).

---

#### Providing context in a question

In any case, I'd venture to say that main reason your phrases "sound incorrect" is that you didn't provide ample context to let them sound correct.

Consider this example:

> *I want to remind you that*...
>
> Is that something a native speaker would say? Does it sound right, or wrong?

Truth be told, it's hard to say for sure, because we have so little to go on. Look what happens when I set a context instead:

> Suppose a group of teenagers are causing a commotion at the library. The librarian approaches them, and says:
>
> *I want to remind you that we expect patrons to be quiet in a library*.
>
> Is that acceptable English?

With the additional context, the question becomes much easier to analyze and answer.

---

#### “Venture to Say”

Now, back to your example:

> I venture to say that...

Does that sound acceptable, or awkward? Well, I don't think I would ever say to my friend at a rugby match:

> *I venture to say that the home team is having trouble moving the ball*.

(That sounds too stilted for the rugby stands). However, I might say to my boss:

> *I was a little nervous giving bad news to the manager, but I ventured to hint that the project might not be on-time*.

---

> I would like to venture that...

That one sounds off. You could say:

> I would like to say that our research might be going in the wrong direction.

or:

> I would venture that our research might be going in the wrong direction.

but "would like to venture" seems like too many layers of indirectness.

---

#### In conclusion

Lastly, a quote from NOAD:

> **venture** (*v.*) 1. dare to do something or go somewhere that may be dangerous or unpleasant
> 2. dare to do or say something that may be considered audacious (often used as a polite expression of hesitation or apology)

Context is everything. Check the [meaning](http://www.onelook.com/?w=venture&ls=a), check [published usages](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ventured%20to%20disagree%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&channel=sb&tbm=bks). Then, if the word fits, venture to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much. No one had answered me that extensively up to now. You are absolutely right. I will do that from now on @J.R. ;)

Comment: Great research, but you missed the more common wording "take/took the liberty **of** (gerund)". [This](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=took+the+liberty+to%2Ctake+the+liberty+to%2C(have+the+right+to+*+0.5)%2C+took+the+liberty+of%2C+take+the+liberty+of&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=8) is the amended N-gram.

Comment: Also interesting, but off-topic, is the comparison between "have the right to" and "have a right to".

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I agree. Also, in the 'A' versions, replacing 'to' with 'for' would make more sense.

'To' is used when someone or something moves toward, or in the direction of something. So, in these examples,

> I take the liberty to disagree.
>
> I take the liberty to say that...

I don’t find something  moving in any direction.

You can better emphasize it using ‘For’, since you are indicating something.

> I take the liberty for saying that.
>
> I take the liberty for disagreeing.

I request other members to provide a better explanation.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! This better goes as a comment Bharat. When you answer, it should be explanatory.

Comment: @MaulikV thanks, but It says I should have 50 reputations to comment. How do I express myself then?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of that. Well, in that case, you may simply make this comment as an answer by explaining it why you agree with OP (Original Poster) and why replace 'to' with 'for'?

Comment: @downvoter, though mouse-clicking is fun, it's better if we explain and justify the downvoting especially to a person who is very new to this board. Just to encourage. (To the O.P.): http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/to%20venture%20to%20disagree Check out these examples and you may edit your answer. All the best!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would like to point out that the information in this answer is not correct. **To** certainly does not only apply in case motion is mentioned, it has lots of other uses. Substituting "for" in those sentences makes them sound awkward, non-standard, and a lot of people will feel they are " wrong".

Comment: "_To_ is used when someone or something moves toward, or in the direction of something." Ahem. No. Think harder. It's rare that we can summarize all the uses of a preposition so succinctly. _Teach manners to your children. He is married to my cousin. Let's listen to the radio. The odds are 8-to-1. We hope these talks bring an end to hostilities. It's 15 minutes to sunrise. The excited crowd danced to the music. I'm starved to death! Let's eat._ NOAD lists 7 definitions; one of them is: "concerning or likely to concern (something, esp. something abstract)". _To_ is the correct preposition here.

Comment: As for how to gain 50 points, you'll have to either ask a few good questions, or leave a few good answers. I recommend doing a lot of research first, though, either way. The best answers here are substantiated with research. For example, did you look up _to_ in a dictionary before you stated its meaning? Had you looked at [this excellent resource](http://www.onelook.com/?w=to), you would have seen that there are many ways that word can be used. That all said, I, too, welcome you to ELL, and hope you stick around until you get the hang of it. We're not mean, but we strive for quality here.

Comment: @J.R.Thank you for the suggestions- points noted. I will definitely research resources before answering or putting my questions on this forum.